# How to find third party apps content providers URI in android?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

Lets say I have installed a third party app & I want to access the content provider which is in that app.

How would I know the authority part of the URI?

I mean how can I know what the developer have assigned for android:authorities="" for provider  with in manifest file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking at the documentation, you can grab the content providers on a device by using:

[public abstract List queryContentProviders (String processName, int uid, int flags)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#queryContentProviders%28java.lang.String,%20int,%20int%29)

This implies that you grab the processName/UID of the application you're looking for.

Learn more here:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html